# What happens if i don't mark a non-serializable field as transient in java?

Tags: java

```
public class PersistentAnimation implements Serializable, Runnable
         {
         private Thread animator;
         private int animationSpeed;
         public PersistentAnimation(int animationSpeed)
        {
         this.animationSpeed = animationSpeed;
        animator = new Thread(this);
           }
               public void run()
          {
             while(true)
            {
               // do animation here
         }
```

Here animator is not marked as transient? Will it still be persisted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because Thread does not implement the `Serializable` interface. You'll have an exception when trying to serialize an instance of this class.

Straight from the [javadoc of Serializable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not
>   support the Serializable interface. In this case the
>   NotSerializableException will be thrown and will identify the class of
>   the non-serializable object.

Answer (score 1):

Java will try to serialize it, see that it's not `Serializable`, and throw a `NotSerializableException`.